# How can I increase my chances of reverse finding an image on Google Images

Tags: images, education, plagiarism

Every now and then I'm grading students and catch a case of plagiarism. Often, some part of the work stands out because it's better than what the student normally does. Usually, I just take a screenshot of the suspicious part, remove any clutter around it and reverse Google it. If I'm not successful and still have doubts, I'll try with the flipped image. Also, sometimes I'll add a keyword or two along with the image and it does the job.

I was checking an image today and had tons of hits of similar images. I had a feeling that the cropping really made a difference but I didn't have the original, just a modified flattened version of what I think might be plagiarized.

I ended up asking the student for their original image. I figured it looks bad if they are not willing to provide it...

Are there other tricks which can be leveraged to help with reverse searching an image?

Comment: Opposite of "[Preventing reverse search engines from finding the origin of your image?](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/q/36491/63979)".

Comment: While interesting, I'm not entirely sure what this has to do with graphic design. To me, this is a "how to use Google" question which may fit better at SuperUser.com or perhaps Academia.SE given the nature of the "how to".  However, it's being up voted.. So.. well... okay.

Comment: @Scott I think it's relevant mostly for graphic design educators, and I agree it's a bit of a niche thing. I hesitated a bit but figured it might find more use here for other educators.

Comment: @WELZ I agree it has a lot of common with the opposite question (thanks for pointing it out!) but I think the answers may differ slightly (e.g. Ovaryraptor's suggestion of using TinyEye wouldn't work for the opposite question)

Comment: The other question is "How to hide images from being searched" yours is "How to find 'hidden' images in reverse search".

Comment: @WELZ Yes, while it's "reversed" it doesn't mean the answer is exactly the same. For example, "How can I make my teacher like me?" and "How can I piss my teacher off?" likely you would have some answers that are opposite in meaning but you might have an extra element or two in there. This is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4):

Try [TinEye](https://www.tineye.com/) as well. Other than that there is a hard limit on how accurately an image can be reverse-searched.

It sounds like you have a good method in place already but I would also search tutorial sites and the like. Usually people won't go very deep and use the first few things that pop-up on a search.